# How to add source to the Java build?

Tags: java

I am developing an IntelliJIdea plugin and I need to add a file to the build - the plugin has to copy this file to the user's source folder during use.

I placed this file in the `/resources` folder and this file exists in the build (in the appropriate .jar file), but I can't get a path to this file.

I try to get a path to the folders of my build but I receive a `null` for all cases:

```java
class ImageUtils{
   private void m() {
       InputStream resourceAsStream = new ImageUtils().getClass().getResourceAsStream("commonImg.png");
       URL classResource = ImageUtils.class.getClass().getResource("ImageUtils.class");
       URL imageResource = ImageUtils.class.getClass().getResource("");
       URL systemResource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("");
       URL location = ImageUtils.class.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
   }
}
```

Which way is correct to implement such logic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Option 1 - Prefix path with `/`

```java
InputStream stream = ImageUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/commonImg.png");
```

Option 2 - Get via `ClassLoader` instead of `Class`

```java
ClassLoader loader = ImageUtils.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("commonImg.png");
```

Comment: 'go via classloader' is an anti-pattern. It _seems_ to work, but in various contexts (admittedly, exotic ones, such as agents), `getClassLoader()` returns `null` and that code no longer works. It's pernicious: It's hard to test and harder to find out the code has unknown caveats, which on one hand is good news (it rarely goes wrong!), but also bad news (... but if it does you won't find out until production where bugs are considerably more pricey!). The right move is to stop spreading it on sites like SO. `X.class.getResource` is the only answer that should be given.

Comment: I disagree that loading via classloader is an anti-pattern. Do you have any links / docs discussing this rather than your personal opinion?. I always load via classloader and never load via class.

Comment: No, the burden of proof is on you: You decided to make your code longer (`x.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo")` is more complicated than `x.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo")` - so, you have to show why it's worth the extra complication to add that call to `gCL()`). Nevertheless: [here you go](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--). Specifically the text _Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader._ Your version would NPE. The right version would work as normal.

Comment: Being in a context where you're on the bootstrap occurs in various situations. When you're part of the core libs, of course, but that's unlikely. It can also occur when you are an agent. So, if I write an agent and use your library inside my agent, your library now throws NPE for no good reason. It also occurs if you add something to the `-bootclasspath`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, by the way. Paraphrased: "I don't want just an opinion, I want hard facts. So, can you link me to some opinions"? That makes no sense. You should be asking for code snippets showing off a situation where it breaks, or at least trusted docs that make it clear how one would craft such a situation. I have hopefully accomplished this in the comments above: Simply ensure you're in a bootstrap loader scenario and voila, your preferred option NPEs whereas my preferred option works correctly. I trust this is sufficient to disabuse you of your preference.

Comment: Often resources are configured in property files etc. It's nice not to have to prefix paths with slashes. I think we know that `ImageUtils` is not from the bootstrap classpath

Comment: I was asking for some further reading... so I could investigate... wasn't trying to be rude

Comment: I can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) that `Class.getResource(...)` delegates to `ClassLoader.getResource(...)` in normal (non-bootstrap) cases. Since we know that `ImageUtils` is not from the bootstrap classpath I still argue my code is fine. Also, delegating to `ClassLoader.getResource(...)` removes the leading slash which I could argue is unnecessary string manipulation / delegation. I still 100% prefer classloader

Comment: Adding a slash is `"/" +` which is considerably simpler to understand, and as resource loading is not a thing you're going to do a few million times per hour, attempting to optimize out the string concat would be an example of early optimization (i.e. a very bad reason). Whether ImageUtils is in bootstrap or not is not something you can tell from this question.

Comment: Typically only core classes (eg classes in `rt.jar`) will be loaded by the bootstrap classloader. Everything else is loaded by a child classloader. In this insance it was quite clear to me that `ImageUtils` was the OP's custom class and not a core class from `rt.jar`. Regardless many third party libraries load resources via the classloader (eg no slash prefix required on the path). It's common practice to do this. Requiring a leading slash feels a bit dirty to me. I'd take the pepsi challenge here and argue more developers would vote for `ClassLoader.getResource(...)`

Comment: I gotta agree with rzwitserloot here, my own experience is that using the classloader is a bad idea. I was loading resources from the classpath. Everything worked fine, I had unit tests, which worked both locally and when executed from CI/CD pipeline. But when the project was deployed on the test environment, classloaders were unable to locate the resource, despite the fact that it was clearly in the deployed jar (I even inspected the jar manually, it was there). I tried every classloader I could get my hands on, and none worked. In the end only `Class.getResourceAsStream` did the job.

Comment: @Chaosfire that's quite strange since `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)` delegates to `Class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)` under the hood (unless boostrap)

Comment: @lance-java Keyword: _Typically_. Your only reason so far is 'I like writing `.getClassLoader()` because this is better than writing `"/" +`. Which, well, I think we can stop talking there. That's just a bizarre conclusion to me.

Comment: I dislike `Class.getResource(...)` because the path is relative to the class' package (unless you start with "/"). I just don't like starting at an arbitrary location like that and prefer to start from the root, not a specific / semi-random package on the classpath. I'm happy with my choice, sounds like you're happy with yours

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is:

```
ImageUtils.class
```

This expression is of type `java.lang.Class<ImageUtils>` and refers to the j.l.Class object that represents your ImageUtils class. This object has a `getResourceAsStream` method.

> `ImageUtils.class.getClass()`

`ImageUtils.class` returns an instance of `java.lang.Class`. calling `getClass()` on this therefore returns the `java.lang.Class` instance *that represents `java.lang.Class` itself!* - obviously that's no good.

The right way to do this is `ImageUtils.class.getResourceAsStream`.

> `ImageUtils.class.getClass().getResource("");`

That's just not how it works. resources aren't directories and aren't a file system. You can ask **only** for actual 'files' - you cannot ask for directories, or the root, etcetera. If you try to do this, on some combinations of classpaths, loaders, and JVMs that works, but on others, it does not: This is a horrible, horrible bug: One you cannot test for and one that will therefore fail on you much later on, a bug that takes a week to fix as you need to rewrite a ton of infra in your app. The right answer is therefore definitely **not** to try to even go there.

If you need the concept of 'list all entries in this "directory"', you **just cannot do that** with the classloader abstraction. Instead, use SPI: At compile time (either by using something like an annotation processor, or a build system plugin, or even just maintaining this file by hand) you create a file with a well known name that lists every item in your list. Then, you use `getResourceAsStream` to load this file in, read it, and then `getResourceAsStream` every relevant item from it; Tada, we did 'list all contents' without having a command/API to 'list all contents'.

Java itself uses this principle, and the load-the-list part of it is baked in `ServiceLoader`.

> It doesn't work

`ImageUtils.class.getResource("ImageUtils.class")` would work - but it's not one of the things you tried. The `getResource` / `getResourceAsStream` methods on j.l.Class instances are *relative to the package the class is in*. In other words, assuming `ImageUtils` has `package com.foo.hhrzc;` at the top, `getResource("commonImg.png")` will look in the jar file for an entry named `/com/foo/hhrzc/commonImg.png`.

Simply start your resource with a leading slash to tell the loader system: I want to look from the classpath root. So, ask for `.getResourceAsStream("/commonImg.png")` - this will look in the same jar your ImageUtils.class is from, looking for an entry named `/commonImg.png`. (This is why just asking for `"ImageUtils.class"` does work - that is in the jar at `/com/foo/hhrzc/ImageUtils.class`, of course).

Caveats:

- You can't have more than one dot in the file name for silly reasons.
- `ClassLoader` instances also have these `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` methods, but they are 'absolute' (look from the root) out of the box, and in fact always fail if you start with leading slashes. This leads to confusion: If you want to look from root, you have to include a leading slash for `j.l.Class.getResource`, but must not use one if calling that method on `j.l.ClassLoader`. Using these methods on classloader is pretty much always worse than just using them on Class. The canonical, simplest, most idiomatic, most generalized (As in, works every time, no weird exceptions) way to load known resources is with the syntax: `SomeClass.class.getResource("resourceName")` where resourceName, if absolute, needs to start with a slash.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is amazing how much effort you spent on the answer. I started implementing a solution from the getResourceAsStream(), and to my shame, I didn't figure out I had to start from slash. I appreciated your attention to this issue, I rated your answer as useful, but sorry, I'll accept another one - it is clearer for fellow seekers.